# Ratchet Websocket async mysql best practice

Tags: php, nginx, websocket, ratchet

I've build a Websocket chat based on ratchet that uses reactphp async mysql and just got a couple of questions to make sure I'm doing things right, as I couldn't really find any examples for that case out there.

The use case of the Socket is a livechat that handles many different pages at the same time, about 20 pages with 1000+ Users.
Actually this works for now with 100 users, but I have doubts about the database connection to block or queue too many queries with more than thousand users at the same time.
I need to make sure the server can handle everything fast.

Ratchet: https://github.com/ratchetphp/Ratchet

Mysql: https://github.com/friends-of-reactphp/mysql

So, the Socket will be used by different applications, each of them has it's own database where the data has to be stored and published, which means there are multiple Lazy connections created, this is done by the Ratchet Pusher.
There is one database locally on the Websocket server that stores all connected interfaces in one table, out of there the connections are distributed.

The push-server starts the event loop and passes the mysql factory to the pusher constructor (push-server.php):

```html
require dirname(__DIR__).'/websocket/vendor/autoload.php';

use React\MySQL\Factory;
use React\MySQL\QueryResult;

$loop = React\EventLoop\Factory::create();
$factory = new Factory($loop);
$pusher = new websocket01\Pusher($factory);

$webSock = new React\Socket\Server('0.0.0.0:8090', $loop);
$webServer = new Ratchet\Server\IoServer(
    new Ratchet\Http\HttpServer(
        new Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer(
            new Ratchet\Wamp\WampServer(
                $pusher
            )
        )
    ),
    $webSock
);

$loop->run();
```

The Pusher then creates a lazy connection for each connected Interface in the constructor, and thats my second question: **Is it better to create just one async db connection at all and keep it alive (like now), or is is better to reopen the connection at every client interaction ?**

(Pusher.php):

```
protected $connection;
protected $subconnections = array();

public function __construct($factory){
    //Main Websocket db
    $uri = 'localhost...';
    $this->connection = $factory->createLazyConnection($uri);

    //Create array with Connections to Sub dbs for every entry in the interface table
    $stream = $this->connection->queryStream('SELECT * from interfaces');

    $stream->on('data', function ($interface) use ($factory) {

            if (!array_key_exists($interface['interface_dbhost'], $this->subconnections)) {
                $uri = "".$interface['interface_dbuser'].":".$interface['interface_dbpass']."@".$interface['interface_dbhost'].":".$interface['interface_dbport']."/".$interface['interface_dbname']."";

                $this->subconnections[$interface['interface_dbhost']] = $factory->createLazyConnection($uri);
            }
    });
    $stream->on('end', function () {
        echo 'Completed.';
    });
}
```

The main (local) database will still be used to save clients data, errors, verify tokens etc.

The right database connection will then be chosen in onopen, onsubscribe, onpublish... automatically out of the subconnections array, depending on the application the client comes from, and the action he wants to perfom, for e.g:

```
public function onPublish(ConnectionInterface $conn, $conversation_id, $event, array $exclude, array $eligible) {
    $obj = json_decode($event);
    $interface = $obj->frontend;
    $channel = $obj->channel;

    $db = $this->selectDatabase($conversation_id, $interface); //Choose right database connection
    $clienthandler = new Clienthandler\Clienthandler($this->connection);

    $action = $this->processRequest($db,$obj, $conversation_id, $clienthandler, $operatorhandler, $channel);
}
```

I'm also passing the local db connection to the clienthandler too, as I need it there to log actions.

```
public function selectDatabase($conversation_id, $interface) {
        if(array_key_exists($interface, $this->subconnections)) {
            $dbconn = $this->subconnections[$interface];

            $dbconn->ping()->then(function () {
                echo 'Connection alive' . PHP_EOL;
            }, function (Exception $e) {
                echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage() . PHP_EOL;
            });
        }
    }
    return $dbconn;
}
```

The clienthandler then saves the data and broadcasts it to all subscribers

I'm open for any advice :-)

Thank you for your help

Comment: please define "best". What you mean by that would depend on the requirements and goals of the application, and any issues you think are there at present. As you say it's currently "working perfectly", it's unclear what improvements you think are needed or what future problems you foresee. As such it's impossible for us to give you any meaningful advice really.

Comment: I've editet the text regarding the requirements and goals, is it more clear now?
@ADyson

Comment: `Is it better to create just one async db connection at all and keep it alive (like now), or is is better to reopen the connection at every client interaction ?` I assume you mean better for performance? Or memory use? Or is it something else? ...but for performance, but which I guess is usually the thing people worry about - that really depends on the underlying database library and driver...

Comment: ...Some database libraries will use connection pooling under the hood anyway such that opening and closing a connection in the code doesn't always open a physical connection, instead it simply selects an already-open connection from the pool, if one is available.

Comment: you are right, better for performance.

The lazy connections are what I already use, what I wanna know is if it matters to open the lazy connections already in the constructor from the Pusher like I do now, or open it everytime a client publishes to a topic

thank you very much for your help

Comment: This lazy connections concept in that library is not the same as traditional connection pooling really. What's most efficient probably depends on the usage pattern of your app - if you expect lots of incoming data from each user which needs saving frequently, then it's probably better to try and use as few connection objects as possible and keep connections open. But if the saving would be more intermittent, you could end up with issues where connections are open and can't be re-used by another user. (Also it depends whether ratchet shares the connection between all websocket users or not.)

Comment: ok I understand. 
In my case, every client will either get a result back with about 300 to 1000 rows everytime he opens a chat window, or simply make one insert to a table when he sends a message from this window which does not take long at all. So I might go ahead with that solution I have and if there are problems later, I will create one lazy connection for each client